# Monitoring Azure Website

Tags: performance, azure, cloud, monitoring

I want to write a program that displays the monitoring data that you see on the Azure management portal.

- The program should monitor Website and not storage or web/worker role
- can Windows Azure API provide access to all the data that is exposed on the portal??

Please suggest how can I get started with this. Should I consider converting website to worker role?

Forgive me for the lame question as I am very new to Azure and Cloud

Comment: What do mean monitor azure website? Do you mean to monitor your services health? If your question was to monitor health of your services then it is a good question to ask.

Comment: check this out to monitor your services through grafana: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/monitor-azure-services-and-applications-using-grafana/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe the Windows Azure Website monitoring data is publically exposed at this time.  Maybe once the service GA's?

If you want detailed metrics (performance counters), then you'll need to use a web/worker role.